# Apple IAP Custom Discount

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

Another struggle with the App Store.

We're doing a treasure hunt in our city with the smart phone. It will include a lot of real-world stuff combined with AR-Stuff in the Phone.

So, to promote it, we want to make custom discounts for in-app-purchase.

Say, the base price to do the treasure hunt is 6 Dollar. We'd give some people, like students at the local university 50% discount codes. So, they can buy it a Ticket for 3 Dollars.

We've read the Apple Guideline on IAP, but it's not conclusive. Has anybody made any experiences with the App Store Review on Custom Discount Codes or Promo Codes? Does Apple allow Promo Codes?

(We know there is a function to generate 100 Promo Codes, but it's not what we're looking for.)

Any help on that matter is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Simplest solution: Create the logic you want and then setup a new IAP with the discount and "display" that one through your custom logic (and not the default IAP). Besides promo codes there is no other mechanism/way to discount your IAPs.

Comment: hi @Stefan you got solution ?